# Oracle Database 11g Express: Errors and Exception Handling

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a procedure that runs a query that returns no data, made on purpose to test the error handling:

```
create or replace procedure archive_aggreg(p_to_date in date) 
is

 v_lname VARCHAR2 (15);
begin

       SELECT city INTO v_lname
         FROM CHAIN1;


    FOR Lcntr IN 1..100000
LOOP
   INSERT INTO CHAIN1 VALUES (1, TO_CHAR(p_to_date, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),  TO_CHAR(p_to_date, 'FMMonth DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
END LOOP;   

commit;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DECLARE
         l_code   INTEGER := SQLCODE;
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO T_LOG (  
                               error_code
                              ,  error_message
                              ,  backtrace
                              ,  callstack
                              ,  created_on
                              ,  created_by)
              VALUES (
                    l_code
                    ,  sys.DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_stack
                    ,  sys.DBMS_UTILITY.format_error_backtrace
                    ,  sys.DBMS_UTILITY.format_call_stack
                    ,  SYSDATE
                    ,  USER);

         RAISE;
      END;

end;
```

excepting the error to be inserted in the table `T_LOG`, but is not the case, but in the PL/SQL Developer console I got this message:

```
ORA-01403: no data found
```

Comment: Do you mean you got that error message when you **created** the procedure, or when you subsequently **ran** it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [RAISE statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/raise_statement.htm) at the end of the exception block:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
         ......
         ......
         RAISE;
      END;
end;
```

This command raises the error to the calling subprogram. The whole PL/SQL statement (begin-end block in your procedure which is treated as a single statement) is rolled back, including rows inserted by the INSERT statements, since Oracle supportst [statement level atomicy](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/transact.htm#CNCPT1115)

> **Statement-Level Atomicity**
>
> Oracle Database supports statement-level atomicity, which means that a
>   SQL statement is an atomic unit of work and either completely succeeds
>   or completely fails.
>
> A successful statement is different from a committed transaction. A
>   single SQL statement executes successfully if the database parses and
>   runs it without error as an atomic unit, as when all rows are changed
>   in a multirow update.
>
> **If a SQL statement causes an error during execution, then it is not
>   successful and so all effects of the statement are rolled back. This
>   operation is a statement-level rollback.** This operation has the
>   following characteristics:
>
> - A SQL statement that does not succeed causes the loss only of work it would have performed itself.
> - The unsuccessful statement does not cause the loss of any work that preceded it in the current transaction. For example, if the execution
>     of the second UPDATE statement in "Sample Transaction: Account Debit
>     and Credit" causes an error and is rolled back, then the work
>     performed by the first UPDATE statement is not rolled back. The first
>     UPDATE statement can be committed or rolled back explicitly by the
>     user.
> - The effect of the rollback is as if the statement had never been run.
>
> Any side effects of an atomic statement, for example, triggers invoked
>   upon execution of the statement, are considered part of the atomic
>   statement. Either all work generated as part of the atomic statement
>   succeeds or none does.